# .NET Core untrobustive ajax - работает на тексте, но подгружает страницу для textarea и select

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

В одном файле **cshtml** есть 3 формы рядом.

**Textarea**

```html
<form data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="post" asp-action="EditBookAnnotation"
      asp-controller="EditBook" asp-route-bookId=@Model.Book.Id method="post"
      enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="container d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <textarea onchange="this.form.submit()" class="form-control"
                              placeholder="Поменять аннотацию" name="annotation" required
                              rows="6">@Model.Book.Annotation</textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

**Select + options**

```html
<form data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="post" asp-action="EditBookStatus"
      asp-controller="EditBook" asp-route-bookId=@Model.Book.Id method="post"
      enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="container d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="goodSelect">
                    <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="status" type="text">
                        <option selected hidden>@Model.Book.Status</option>
                        <option>Начало</option>
                        <option>В процессе</option>
                        <option>Закончена</option>
                        <option>Заброшена</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**И просто Input типа text**

```html
<form data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="post" asp-action="EditBookName"
      asp-controller="EditBook" asp-route-bookId=@Model.Book.Id method="post"
      enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="container d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <input onblur=" if(text.count > 0) this.form.submit()" required
                       type="text" class="form-control" name="newName"
                       value="@Model.Book.BookName">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Все они заточены на то, чтобы работать без кнопок, поменял значение - и оно отправляется.

Но по какой то причине как AJAX работает только простой `input text`, а все остальные - `select` и `textarea` при сабмите почему то загружают то что они получают от сервера.

**Вопрос** - почему так и как этого избежать? Мне надо чтобы при изменении значений в `select` оно просто отправляло значение на сервер, а не перезагружало страницу, когда получит от него ответ.